# Optimizing grep (or using AWK) in a shell script

Tags: shell, awk, grep

In my shell script, I am trying to search using terms found in a $sourcefile against the same $targetfile over and over.

My $sourcefile is formatted as such:

```
pattern1
pattern2
etc...
```

The inefficient loop I have to search with is:

```
for line in $(< $sourcefile);do
    fgrep $line $targetfile | fgrep "RID" >> $outputfile
done
```

I understand it would be possible to improve this by either loading the whole $targetfile into memory, or perhaps by using AWK?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just join the sourcefile and egrep for (pattern1|pattern2...)?

Comment: Good idea...would need to egrep for like 4000 options though...the patterns would vary based on how many lines in the sourcefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am I missing something, or why not just `fgrep -f "$sourcefile" "$targetfile"`?

Comment: WOW!  This was faster than the other two.  The results seem proper, too.  I mean, lightning lightning fast.  Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

A sed solution:

`sed 's/\(.*\)/\/\1\/p/' $sourcefile | sed -nf - $targetfile`

This transforms every line of $sourcefile to a sed pattern match command:

> matchstring

to

> /matchstring/p

You'd need to escape special characters to make this robust, however.

Comment: Thanks!  Giving this a try now.  Already seems faster than using grep, albeit the source file has about 4000 lines and is searching against a 300 meg target file, so I expect it will still take a bit of time.  Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk to read in the sourcefile then searching in targetfile (untested):

```
nawk '
    NR == FNR {patterns[$0]++; next}
    /RID/ {
        for (pattern in patterns) {
            # since fgrep considers patterns as strings not regular expressions, 
            # use string lookup and not pattern matching ("~" operator).
            if (index($0, pattern) > 0) {
                print
                break
            }
        }
    }
' "$sourcefile" "$targetfile" > "$outputfile"
```

Will also with with `gawk`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will also give this a try.

Comment: Was pretty fast but the fgrep -f as suggested was more what I needed.